# Advice on commerical kitchen layout

Tags: equipment, rice-cooker, induction, kitchen

I'm setting up a commerical delivery only kitchen and so far I have a flat top grill and fryers. Beside these under the hood i need to add induction hobs for cooking potatoes and pasta and rice cookers. Does anyone know how these types of equipment would normally be positioned in a commerical kitchen? Like do people put induction hobs on a work bench that would be the hight of a normal stove? or, seeing as the pots are quite large, would people position these on lower down tables? Many thanks!

Comment: Some pots are deep, others aren't, even cooking commercially. I'm just back from my one week a year that involves cooking in a commercial kitchen and the new induction cooker was at a similar height to home (prep surfaces a little higher than home, sinks really deep of course). We used frying pans quite a bit as well as deep pots for simmering large quantities. Just one data point.